# How do I trigger a function from my javascript component that may or may not exist in the file importing it?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a Javascript project using Webpack, Babel, and ES6. I have a section of code (a filters box) that is reused on multiple pages. The pages are slightly different. One of the filters is called "locations". It is a single select box. One of the pages that uses this component has a second select box called "alternate locations" which is outside of the filters component (lower on the page) but this one is a multi-select box. Both boxes are populated with the same options but the first 10 options are selected by default on the multi-select box. After the options are populated the multi-select box has to be initialized because it is a fancy box with a search from Kendo UI. The options are returned by an ajax call that is made from my component file (component.js). Currently I am doing all of this in the success function.

My problem is that I am importing this JavaScript file on the pages that need it and I do not want to include any references to the multi-select in this file since it is not really part of the component I am making and usually won't exist on the page. Each page has its own JavaScript file (page1.js, page2.js...). Each of these files are requiring my component's file (require(./component.js)) at the top.

How do I let the importing file (page2.js for example) know when my ajax call succeeded so that it can initialize the multi-select while component.js handles initializing the single select?

Comment: To check whether a function is defined, you may use `typeof xxx === 'function'`. Can not really judge whether this is the correct solution for you tho.

Comment: So unfortunately component.js doesn't know what functions were defined in pageX.js because component.js is imported into pageX.js, not the other way around. I'm wondering if maybe I should create a custom event in each pageX.js file and somehow trigger that event when the api returns in component.js. Of course, if the api happens to return super fast then there might be an issue still.